# How to create a histogram from a 2d array F#

Tags: arrays, f#, histogram

How would I create a histogram from a 2d array in F#.

I have tried something like this:

```
let histogram =
    Array.iter (fun acc fs -> 
        fs |> List.iter (fun k -> 
            if Map.containsKey k acc
            then Map.add k (acc.[k] + 1) acc
            else Map.add k 1 acc
        )
    ) Map.empty
```

But I really cannot get my head around how to solve this.
Any suggestions to kickstart me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i you right understand:

```
let arr = [| [|1; 2; 4 |] ;[|3; 2; 4 |] ;[|1; 7; 4 |] |]
arr |> Array.concat |> Array.sort |> Seq.groupBy id |> Seq.map(fun el -> fst el,Seq.length (snd el)) 
|> Seq.iter(fun x -> printfn "%d [%d]" (fst x) (snd x)))
```

Out:

```
1 [2]
2 [2]
3 [1]
4 [3]
7 [1]
```

http://ideone.com/P5hmtU

Comment: FWIW, you may replace `Seq.groupBy id |> Seq.map(fun el -> fst el,Seq.length (snd el))` by `Seq.countBy id`

Comment: kaefer, Thanks. Your variant is much better

Comment: Can't quiet get it to work, but just found out that the format is like, a list of arrays:
[2; 19]
[3; 13]
[2; 2; 2; 5]
[41]
[2; 3; 7]
[43]
[2; 2; 11]
[3; 3; 5]
[2; 23]
[47]

Comment: Solved it by this: arr |> List.concat |> List.sort |> Seq.countBy id. Thanks for your help!